# NSSortDescriptor for NSArrayController to sort alphabetically and by string length

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsarraycontroller, nssortdescriptor

I have an NSArrayController and I'm trying to sort it base on length of the string and also alphabetically. The NSArrayController contains a string with space like this " ".

Here is my code:

```
    NSSortDescriptor *nameSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *lengthSorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"length" ascending:YES];
[self.nameAC.content setSortDescriptors:@[lengthSorter, nameSortDescriptor]];
```

But this is the result of the sort:

[image]
What I need to s first the string " " and after aaa, bbb, cccc, ddd.

The output in console of NSArrayController (nameAC):

```
(lldb) po _nameAC
<NSArrayController: 0x6080001c05a0>[entity: Tags, number of selected objects: 1]
```

The output in console of the NSArrayController content is the following:

(lldb) po _nameAC
[entity: Tags, number of selected objects: 1]

```
(lldb) po _nameAC.content
<__NSArrayM 0x60000004f600>(
<Tags: 0x6000000a7260> (entity: Tags; id: 0x140002b <x-coredata://B7756C1E-B9F2-4C57-A1FA-272478C4D6A6/Tags/p5> ; data: {
    category = "0x40000b <x-coredata://B7756C1E-B9F2-4C57-A1FA-272478C4D6A6/Categories/p1>";
    product = "<relationship fault: 0x60800002ba80 'product'>";
    name = bbb;
}),
<Tags: 0x6000000a7200> (entity: Tags; id: 0x100002b <x-coredata://B7756C1E-B9F2-4C57-A1FA-272478C4D6A6/Tags/p4> ; data: {
    category = "0x40000b <x-coredata://B7756C1E-B9F2-4C57-A1FA-272478C4D6A6/Categories/p1>";
    product = "<relationship fault: 0x60800002a160 'product'>";
    name = aaa;
}),
<Tags: 0x6000000a7740> (entity: Tags; id: 0x1c0002b <x-coredata://B7756C1E-B9F2-4C57-A1FA-272478C4D6A6/Tags/p7> ; data: {
    category = "0x40000b <x-coredata://B7756C1E-B9F2-4C57-A1FA-272478C4D6A6/Categories/p1>";
    product = "<relationship fault: 0x60800002b940 'product'>";
    tagName = ddd;
}),
<Tags: 0x6000000a5ca0> (entity: Tags; id: 0x40002b <x-coredata://B7756C1E-B9F2-4C57-A1FA-272478C4D6A6/Tags/p1> ; data: {
    category = "0x40000b <x-coredata://B7756C1E-B9F2-4C57-A1FA-272478C4D6A6/Categories/p1>";
    product = "<relationship fault: 0x6080000283e0 'product'>";
    name = " ";
}),
<Tags: 0x6000000a76e0> (entity: Tags; id: 0x180002b <x-coredata://B7756C1E-B9F2-4C57-A1FA-272478C4D6A6/Tags/p6> ; data: {
    category = "0x40000b <x-coredata://B7756C1E-B9F2-4C57-A1FA-272478C4D6A6/Categories/p1>";
    product = "<relationship fault: 0x60800002a620 'product'>";
    name = cccc;
})
)
```

Any of you knows what I'm doing wrong or how can I do this?

I'll really appreciate you help

Comment: Log the array controller's content so we can see the strings for ourselves. Also, from context, I would expect `self.nameAC` to be an `NSArrayController`. It would make sense to set the `sortDescriptors` property on that. However, your code is fetching its `content` and setting `sortDescriptors` on that. That doesn't seem to make sense. What are `self.nameAC` and `self.nameAC.content`?

Comment: self.nameAC is an NSArrayController and  content is a property of the  NSArrayController

Comment: I know that `content` is a property of an `NSArrayController`, but what does it refer to *in your case*? What kind of object is it *in your case*? The property is declared with type `id`, so nobody can guess what you're doing with it unless you tell us. Why are you setting the sort descriptors on that instead of on the array controller itself? Show the result of logging `self.nameAC` and `self.nameAC.content`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content array contains managed objects for the Tags entity. Those objects do have a `name` property, but they don't have a `length` property.

If you want to construct a sort descriptor that sorts by the length of the `name`, you should use the key path `name.length`. So:

```
NSSortDescriptor *lengthSorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name.length" ascending:YES];
```

Also, the sort descriptors should be set on the array controller. So, where you wrote:

```
[self.nameAC.content setSortDescriptors:@[lengthSorter, nameSortDescriptor]];
```

it should be:

```
[self.nameAC setSortDescriptors:@[lengthSorter, nameSortDescriptor]];
```

or just:

```
self.nameAC.sortDescriptors = @[lengthSorter, nameSortDescriptor];
```